# Http REPORT method in ios for ical response

Tags: ios, alamofire, icalendar

I am working on calendar application, i need to hit one api for ical response but that api HTTP method is REPORT,so how can i do it with urlsession or alamofire.For rest apis we have GET,PUT,POST,DELETE but here i need to set REPORT method,will alamofire supports this request

ICal Respone:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid1@example.com
DTSTAMP:19970714T170000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe:MAILTO:john.doe@example.com
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
DTEND:19970715T035959Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: I don't know, but you may have to perform the call (Alamofire or AFNetworking) with a (NS)(Mutable)URLRequest and not a URL, where you could set the `request.HTTPMethod = "REPORT"`

Comment: i tried it is working